# Linear Transformation Matrix from $M_2(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, we are given that $T : M_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is a linear transformation such that $T(A) = B\cdot A \forall A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ where $B$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. I know that $T$ ranges from a  4 dimensional space to  a 4 dimensional space so $M_T(E,E)=C$ (where $E$ is the standard basis) is going to be $4 \times 4$, but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate it. In non-matrix spaces, you just do $T(e_1)$ as the first column of $C$, $T(e_2)$ as the second column, etc. But here $T(e_1)$ is itself a $2\times 2$ matrix. So:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
B\cdot e_1 & B\cdot e_2 & B\cdot e_3 & B\cdot e_4
\end{array}\right)$

won't work as it gives us a $2\times 8$ instead of a $4\times 4$. So how do I arrange $B\cdot e_1$, $B\cdot e_2$, $B\cdot e_3$, and $B\cdot e_4$ into a $4\times 4$ matrix as required?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have figured it out, but someone please confirm this: We take $B(e_1)$ and write it as a linear combination of $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$, and the coefficients on $e_1$ is the first entry in the first column, the coefficient on $e_2$ is the second entry in the first column, etc?

Comment: @walker: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $T(e_1) = B\cdot e_1 = a_1e_1 + b_1e_2 + c_1e_3 + d_1e_4$, $T(e_2) = B\cdot e_2 = a_2e_1 + b_2e_2 + c_2e_3 + d_2e_4$, and so on, the matrix $C$ will be:

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4
\end{array} \right)$